# How can i display custom menu in sidebar?

Tags: customization, menus, register-sidebar

I would like to display a custom menu in a custom sidebar instead of author information or blank space i.e custom menu with similar styles as default menu but only in vertical manner as displayed in grey in the below picture.

[image]

Comment: you can set a custom menu and widget containing wp_nav_menu()

Comment: i have an idea about it....but how to write a full fledged code

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan Check this answer, I use it commonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several plugins to achieve custom menus, So I like to use the plugin [Sidebar Menu Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sidebar-menu-widget/), With this you can create a Menu on your WP Menu options, then assign the menu to the sidebar. I think this is the easier way to have a second menu on sidebars.